# Add product name in static block

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I have **CMS** static block and I must show in this block individual product name.

When I am going to product page I want show name this product in a static block.

How to do this?

Comment: Means You want to set current product name in cms block, and that cms block call in all product page

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your cms block add below code

```
{{block type='core/template' template='YourtemplatePath/yourTemplate.phtml'}}
```

And in your folder create file 
`yourMagentoRoot/app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/YourtemplatePath/yourTemplate.phtml`

and add below code in `yourTemplate.phtml` file

```
<?php
  echo Mage::registry('current_product')->getName();
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a way to directly inject a variable to the CMS,
but you could for instance insert a custom variable to the block like `{{product_name}}` , then get the block in product page:

```
$html = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_id')->toHtml();
```

and then inject your product name:

```
echo str_replace("{{product_name}}",$product->getName(),$html);
```